# Using nodejs chmod 777 and 0777

Tags: node.js, chmod

Using `fs.chmod(path, mode, callback)` I set the mode  to `777`.  It didn't work properly. But when I set it to `0777`, it worked.

So I want to know what the difference is between `chmod 777` and `chmod 0777`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The leading zero in `0777` indicates that the number is an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

The number `777` in octal notation is the number `511` in decimal notation. `fs.chmod(path, 0777)` and `fs.chmod(path, 511)` do the same thing, but `fs.chmod(path, 777)` does not.

The reason for your confusion is that you assumed the file access mode `777` is a decimal number. You might want to read more about the unix [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) program and [file system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_access_permission).